# Largest and Smallest Possible Number

Tags: code-golf

#### Task

Given an array of non-negative numbers, output the largest and smallest possible number that can be formed by joining them.

#### Rules

Input,Output can be in any convenient format.

The array may have at most 1 decimal number.

#### Examples

```
input:[22,33,44,55.55,33]
output:4433332255.55,55.5522333344

input:[34,900,3,11,9]
output:990034311,113349009

input:[99.93,9,3,39]
output:939399.93,99.933399

input:[45.45,45,45,45]
output:45454545.45,45.45454545

input:[12,21,34,43,45.1]
output:4334211245.1,45.112213443
```

This is **code-golf** so shortest code wins.

Comment: Wouldn't the first output be: 4422333355.55, 55.5544333322? Those are smaller and larger respectively.

Comment: @ouflak, you have to output the largest and smallest.

Comment: Nevermind, see it now. Got confused with the decimal place.

Comment: Would `[[55.55,22,33,33,44],[44,33,33,22,55.55]]` be an acceptable output format?

Comment: @Shaggy, no, the output must be 2 numbers only.

Comment: Can I take a list of strings? i.e. `["22", "33", "44", "55.55", "33"]`

Comment: Can we assume that the array contains at least to elements?

Comment: @wastl, list of strings is fine and the array will have at least one element.

Comment: Does the output have to be in (max, min) order, or can it be the other way around?

Comment: Any way is fine @Jordan

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>84</s> <s>80</s> <s>78</s> 76 bytes

```python
lambda a:[''.join(sorted(a,key=lambda s:'.'in s or s+s)[::i])for i in[-1,1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU/BbsMgDL3nK5B2INEyVNtwIFK/JOWQqY3G1pEq5NKvT00IWoaFLT/7PT0/nsvXFHAdz5f1Pvx@XgcxdL2U6nvyoY7TvNyu9dD@3J7nfRw7qaQPIoppFvE9Nn3XedeM3HnhQ/8BLTi3PmYfFjHWvUSUrSTipDUnY5QxGXFN9Sa0Jn6IBd8qYgK1rqo/HUpsezolLn@A1GYNyzBp2iAAJnJvj1xrlaVtP5OpEImjzFIlbo9EbZROrv6l7NvkKHNVgCMd0u2YbG3uNeVV2CXYKQLghuQBIALfTUeRXcM16ws)

<sub>-2 bytes, thanks to Arnauld</sub>

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
Œ!VṢ.ị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJMWwhzsX6T3c3f3///9oQyMdI0MdYxMdE2MdE1M9w1gA)

Explanation:

```
Œ!VṢ.ị Arguments: x
Œ!     Permutations of x
  V    Concatenate the representations of each permutation's elements and evaluate the result as Jelly code
   Ṣ   Sort
    .ị Get element at index 0.5, i.e. elements at indices 0 (last) and 1 (first)
```

Comment: I never program in Jelly, but `.ị` is a pretty cool way of getting both the first and last item of a list. Nice answer! +1 from me.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen It actually gets the last and first item. :P

Comment: I've also never programmed in Jelly, but I'm confused as to how ```.ị``` works. If I'm reading the docs correctly, I would think ```ị``` gets the element of y at floor(x) and ceil(x), and ```.``` is ```0.5```. Doesn't that mean it will get elements of y at index 0 and 1?

Comment: Is Jelly 1-based indexed? That would explain this behavior but I don't see anything about that in the docs.

Comment: @Cowabunghole Yes, Jelly is 1-indexed.

Comment: BTW, why so much interest about this `.ị` here, it's just a normal thing...

Comment: I was interested because Jelly programs usually go over my head but this one was short and simple so I was trying to figure it out. I was able to understand it up to the ```.ị``` and was just confused by the indexing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>14 11</s> 10 bytes

```
á m¬ñn gJò
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///BChdxDaw5vzFNI9zq86f//aEMjHSNDHWMTHRNjHRNTPcNYAA)

Comment: Nice one. I had `á ®¬nÃn` for the first line - kicking myself that I didn't think of your way.

Comment: [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///BChdxDaw5vzOM6vF7h0PrQnP//ow2NdIwMdYxNdEyMdUxM9QxjuXQzAA), using the `-h` flag.

Comment: [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///BChdxDaw5vzOM6vD70cGv5///RhkY6RoY6xiY6JsY6JqZ6hrFcuukA), using the `-g` flag. Also works with `í` instead of `ï`.

Comment: Dang! Looks like I gave up to soon; very nicely done.

Comment: Yep. Oliver helped me in the chat! very clever way to get first and last value from an array!

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, <s>14</s> 11 bytes

```
á m¬ñn é v2
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=4SBtrPFuIOkgdjI=&input=WzIyLDMzLDQ0LDU1LjU1LDMzXQotUQ==)

1 byte saved thanks to [Luis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/176002/58974), please `+1` his solution too.

```
á               :Permutations
  m             :Map
   ¬            :  Join
    ñ           :Sort by
     n          :  Converting each to a number
       é        :Rotate right
         v2     :Remove & return the first 2 elements
```

Comment: Ok, this is better!! damn!! that `é` was hidden all this time!!

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
œJΣ'.¡ï}Á2£
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6GSvc4vV9Q4tPLy@9nCj0aHF//9HGxnpGBvrmJjomJrqmZoC2bEA)
or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/q5hL6/@hkr3OL1fUOLTy8vvZwo9Ghxf91/kcbGekYG@uYmOiYmuqZmgLZsVzRxiY6lgYGOsY6hoY6lkC@paWepbGOJVDAGMQ1MdUzMdWBIaCAoZGOkaEOUJcJ0CRTPcNYAA)

**Explanation**

```
 œ             # get permutations of input
  J            # join each
   Σ    }      # sort by
    '.¡        # splitting into [before decimal, after decimal]
       ï       # and converting each to int
         Á     # rotate the result right
          2£   # and take the first 2 values
```

Comment: Too bad we don't have a `cast to float`. I remember there was one in the Legacy, but I just looked it up and apparently it was a `stringified cast to float`, which is pretty useless since you want floats instead of strings to sort on.. xD

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Yeah. We **had** an `is_number` but unfortunately no `to_number`.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>68</s> 66 bytes

```javascript
a=>[1,-1].map(n=>a.sort((a,b)=>[a%1||a]+b<[b%1||b]+a?n:-n).join``)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDBasMwDIbvewpfBglV3EiyDy5L9yDBUKdrR0tnhybdqe@eKQk7zKdJBkn@pQ@ka/gOw/F@6ccqpo/TdG6m0OxbhAq9/gp9EZt90EO6j0URoCtFC6/4fAa/6d7abk47vwnvcVfFUl/TJR4O5XRMcUi3k76lz@JctETADMaAtdpayX1Zqu1WpcfYP8adMSxGtKpqCUTznzEvGYoNuLoGBkRwXon9QTkR2bCIClHmpXQ5wjntGJwweCVkCBZfWtQSWKocYaw2Fn6fzxHGrj43qSWsnmOQgBBkJSPXsRp9hpEFCJFmaeFITihH4RxUQ62R/j0@/QA)

#### How?

We use the following test to compare two values in the input array:

```javascript
[a % 1 || a] + b < [b % 1 || b] + a
```

The expression `x % 1 || x` returns the decimal part of \$x\$ if \$x\$ is a decimal number, or leaves \$x\$ unchanged otherwise.

The expression `[x % 1 || x] + y` coerces the above result to a string and concatenates it with the other value.

If there's a decimal number in the list, it must always be considered as the smallest value. By applying our conversion, a decimal number is turned into a string starting with `"0."`, which is lexicographically ordered before anything else.

*Examples:*

```
  a |   b | [a%1||a]+b | [b%1||b]+a
----+-----+------------+------------
  4 |   5 | "45"       | "54"
 10 |  11 | "1011"     | "1110"
  8 |  80 | "880"      | "808"
  7 | 9.5 | "79.5"     | "0.57"
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>56</s> 45 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.permutation.map{|p|p.join.to_f}.minmax}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDbasMwDH3fVwj2soEmqosfPNh@pIThjQUymsQUB1bafnumOIylkwxH8tE5WD5O76e5fZmfXtM5Uf489lNJpRsH6lM@X/Il09fYDVTGt/ZKfTf06fs6Z2jpIx0OD3sRVEUzDIFC8Lp5hHsYp5Kn8gxm6iGyklBBZLkzu/szUcO426EiM8YGPLYm0Tk1dQ6YXelt3IhjpKgYXa2r9lasnnUCKqh3G7EFsoC/p/kntrDmMgMV1twYsKAw@gLmvxCIm1sDf64wy8JUB6@FfXmdfwA)

-11 bytes, thanks Jordan

Comment: Nice work! You can save 2 bytes by dropping the parentheses around your argument (`->a{...`) and another 9 by using the handy `minmax` method: https://tio.run/##XVDbasMwDH3fVwj2soEmqosfPNh@pIThjQUymsQUB1bafnumOIylkwxH8tE5WD5O76e5fZmfXtM5Uf489lNJpRsH6lM@X/Il09fYDVTGt/ZKfTf06fs6Z2jpIx0OD3sRVEUzDIFC8Lp5hHsYp5Kn8gxm6iGyklBBZLkzu/szUcO426EiM8YGPLYm0Tk1dQ6YXelt3IhjpKgYXa2r9lasnnUCKqh3G7EFsoC/p/kntrDmMgMV1twYsKAw@gLmvxCIm1sDf64wy8JUB6@FfXmdfwA

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
hM_BSvsM.p`M
```

Outputs in form `[smallest, largest]`. Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hM_BSvsM.p%60M&input=%5B22%2C33%2C44%2C55.55%2C33%5D&debug=0), or verify all the test cases at once [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hM_BSvsM.p%60M&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B22%2C33%2C44%2C55.55%2C33%5D%0A%5B34%2C900%2C3%2C11%2C9%5D%0A%5B99.93%2C9%2C3%2C39%5D%0A%5B45.45%2C45%2C45%2C45%5D%0A%5B12%2C21%2C34%2C43%2C45.1%5D&debug=0).

```
hM_BSvsM.p`MQ   Implicit: Q=eval(input())
                Trailing Q inferred
          `MQ   Stringify all elements of Q
        .p      Generate all permutations of the above
      sM        Concatenate each permutation
     v          Evaluate each as a number
    S           Sort them
  _B            Pair the sorted list with its reverse
hM              Take the first element of each, implicit print
```

*Edit: Saved a byte by taking stringification out of the mapping function. Previous version:* `` hM_BSmvs`Md.p ``

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 41 bytes

```perl6
{.max,.min}o+<<*.permutations.map(*.join)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzdCoJAFITvfYq9iFAbDu7PCZbsSUTCCwWj3RU1SKJn39YgmIuZb5iZ@vlxjm4Tx0Fc45tc9wK50X/Cqa5LmvrZPdduHYNfUjflJd3D6It4yZZuE0N@uBViCHPWKAWtYQyYiTn5FlmjDWxVQUNK2B1YS1bDJqJ/2TAZxl87kQpKIg1NemOSbfwC)

Alternatives:

```perl6
{.max,.min}o+<<*.permutations.map:{.join}
{.max,.min}o{[map +*.join,.permutations]}
{.max,.min}o{+<<map *.join,.permutations}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
§,▼▲morṁsP
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9odXNr///CpyzilrzilrJtb3LhuYFzUP///1sxMiwyMSwzNCw0Myw0NS4xXQ) or [verify all!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fqxGcr52graSga6egpFH8qKmxSFPz0Lb/h5brPJq26dG0Pbn5RQ93NhYH/P//P9rISMfYWMfERMfUVM/UFMiO5Yo2NtGxNDDQMdYxNNSxBPItLfUsjXUsgQLGIK6JqZ6JqQ4MAQUMjXSMDHWAukyAJpnqGcYCAA)

### Explanation

```
§,▼▲m(rṁs)P  -- example input: [2,3,1.1]
          P  -- permutations: [[2,3,1.1],[3,2,1.1],[1.1,3,2],[3,1.1,2],[1.1,2,3],[2,1.1,3]]
    m(   )   -- map the following
                (example with [1.1,2,3])
       ṁs    -- | show each and join: "1.123"
      r      -- | read: 1.123
             -- : [231.1,321.1,1.132,31.12,1.123,21.13]
§,           -- fork and join as tuple
  ▼          -- | min: 1.123
   ▲         -- | max: 321.1
             -- : (1.123,321.1)
```